# is possible someone break the algorythm of my dice game with hashes

Tags: hash

I just want to know how much secure are these games. I coded my own game and now want to know how much secure is.

If for example the hash is visible(before you bet) would be possible decipher this hash trying to break the algorythm and then guess the number in the roll just with this hash? And what i need to learn to know more about this.

For example i will provide some examples of the hashes.

```
1.c910a1337bc486f621fc1b1d8bf72ebf99fba1eb20bbc3834151649f5fd59e40
2.bf09437579722a8378e51b06afef30b5af337ec3472ac6aa6d34e6a1bbb0cf09
3.6a3df2709858f3313c6651133fbb9c177b27aa2d5a6736e01f692e45fb44c948
4.7b2963c6d959f81dad5388389e43e047e336092c005b57a5bc684d0cc7cb19de
```

could someone just with the hashes get the algorythm? and how we can protect of this. how much time would take me to get the algorytm.

Some idea if would be possible to get the algorythm to guess the number?

Answer (score 3):

"Revealing a hash beforehand" does not mean the algorithm is broken.  We call this a "commitment," and its a well recognized tool.  However, that doesn't mean that an algorithm which uses commitments is not also broken.  You have to analyze the algorithm.

As an extreme example, if you were committing to a 6 sided die roll, and didn't use a nonce, then there's only 6 possible commitments, and its trivial to see what was committed.

Comment: A game could, for example, have a `gameID`. You could create `sha512(result + gameID + nonce)` and publish it before the bets are made. If the nonce is very long, then guessing the correct result is nigh impossible before the bets must be made. If one were to use PBKDF2 or a similarly adjustable function, you could make it even slower to crack.

Comment: What is nonce i dont undertstand what mean this word. I just know that exist a hash , a result  hash, the game id im not sure which is (maybe is hidden not sure) and nonce i dont know what is this ?

Comment: @omaromar A [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) is a random value which is only ever used once. It's used in situations like this to prevent replay attacks. As long as the server picks a different nonce every time, the hashes will be different every time.